# Cant find source of NSURLErrorDoman Code=-2000 "can't load from network"

Tags: watchkit, nsurlsession

Every time I try to pull down data from the host, I'm getting the error shown at the bottom followed by a 4-5 second delay before the completion handler returns without error.  I'm using Xcode, objective-c, and WatchOS.  Any ideas where to look to troubleshoot this?  I tried pulling down data from the iTunes website but had the same issue, so it isn't the host.  Also tried blocking cellular, but that didn't help either.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
config.allowsCellularAccess=NO;
ephemeral=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
relay=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.3/dev/json.php"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask=[ephemeral dataTaskWithURL:relay completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
   //....
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Error from Log:

2018-12-12 19:15:39.894127-0500 EdgeValetWatch WatchKit Extension[7118:261614] Task <6666C271-7428-497B-AA16-2742147FCF9F>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-2000 "can’t load from network" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.3/dev/json.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.3/dev/json.php, NSLocalizedDescription=can’t load from network, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <6666C271-7428-497B-AA16-2742147FCF9F>.<1>"
), NSUnderlyingError=0x7c10e760 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-2000 "(null)"}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <6666C271-7428-497B-AA16-2742147FCF9F>.<1>} [-2000]

Comment: By adding "config.requestCachePolicy=NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;" I was able to silence the error message but still have the 4 second delay.   I'm doing this on the simulator, perhaps this is the cause of the delay?

Comment: Any success? Looks like it happens in Simulator but I've never tried on the real device.

Comment: I broke down and bought a device.  When I run the code on a Series 3 38mm watch, I don't have the delay.  So, I'm guessing it is a simulator-related problem.

Comment: cheers man. Hope the fix the simulator soon